# Change Button-Text (selectfield) - Sencha Touch

Tags: button, localization, sencha-touch

how can i change the button-text ("Done" and "Cancel") in the selectfield to german or in any text i like?

```
xtype: 'selectfield',
    name: 'sector',
    width: 150,
    prependText: 'Sector:',
    options: [
              {text: 'Alle Termine', value: 'alldates'},
             ]
```

Answer (score 0):

one easy possibilty would be to override the defaults of the picker, e.g.:

```
Ext.override(Ext.Picker, {
  doneButton: 'Fertig',
  cancelButton: 'Abbrechen'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Ext.form.Select to allow you to apply your own configuration to the picker it uses.

```
Ext.ns('MySite.ux.form');
MySite.ux.form.Select = Ext.extend(Ext.form.Select , {
    getPicker: function() {
        if (!this.picker) {
            this.picker = new Ext.Picker(Ext.apply({
                slots: [{
                    align       : 'center',
                    name        : this.name,
                    valueField  : this.valueField,
                    displayField: this.displayField,
                    value       : this.getValue(),
                    store       : this.store
                }],
                listeners: {
                    change: this.onPickerChange,
                    scope: this
                }
            }, this.pickerConfig));
        }
        return this.picker;
    }
});
Ext.reg('myselectfield', MySite.ux.form.Select);
```

And your selectfield configuration might look like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'myselectfield',
    name: 'sector',
    label: 'Sector',
    pickerConfig: {
        doneButton: 'Fertig',
        cancelButton: 'Abbrechen'
    }
}
```